# ASP.NET MVC - Custom Model Binder for ID fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders, model-binding, custom-model-binder

i have the following entities:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Section is required")]
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Name is required")]
    public virtual string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public virtual int SectionID { get; set; }
    public virtual string SectionName { get; set; }
}
```

Now within my add category view i have a textbox to enter the SectionID eg:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Section.SectionID) %>
```

I'd like to create a custom model binder to have the following logic:

If the model key ends with ID and has a value (a value was inserted into the textbox) then set the parent object (Section in this example) to Section.GetById(value entered) else set the parent object to null.

I'd really appreciate the help here as this has been baffling me for a while.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the solution posted by dave thieben i have come up with the following:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (bindingContext.ModelType.Namespace.EndsWith("Models.Entities") && value != null && (Utilities.IsInteger(value.AttemptedValue) || value.AttemptedValue == ""))
        {
            if (value.AttemptedValue != "")
                return Section.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(value.AttemptedValue));
            else
                return null;
        }
        else
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

This works nicely, however it doesn't select the right value when the form is posted back and using a drop down list.  I can see why but so far my attempts to fix it have been in vain.  I'd appreciate it once more if you could help.

Comment: if you're still working on this, in the `if` statement you have `value.AttemptedValue == ""` and then on the next line you have `value.AttemptedValue != ""`, so it looks like it would never get to your Section.GetById() code.

Comment: Cheers again for your suggestion but the logic is correct even though it could do with some tidying up to make it more readable.  The solution to the problem was to create a custom DropDownList that handles the Selected property of a SelectItem.  Hopefully they'll fix the bug in the next version of MVC.

Comment: I have a custom model binder [view it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280598/best-way-to-do-partial-update-to-net-mvc-4-model/19297099#19297099) which attempts to sort the properties so that identity fields are always bound first. I let the actual view model class -within it's property setters- trigger it's own repository load rather than have the custom binder do it. (after re-reading your O.P. I realize this isn't a total fit, but, maybe will give someone else an idea)

Answer (score 2):

I posted a model binder on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662651/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-foreign-key-relationship/2971105#2971105) that uses an IRepository to fill foreign keys if they are present.  you could modify it to suit your purpose better.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It really helped in what i have so far.  If you could check out my attempted solution and help complete it that would be muchly appreciated :).